# Why does Bazel say that globals such as 'rule' are not defined?

Tags: bazel

I'm following a tutorial on adding custom toolchains: https://bazel.build/tutorials/cc-toolchain-config

At step 6 I get errors:

```
ERROR: ... : name 'cc_common' is not defined
ERROR: ... : name 'rule' is not defined
ERROR: ... : name 'CcToolchainConfigInfo' is not defined
```

Step 6:

```
def _impl(ctx):
    return cc_common.create_cc_toolchain_config_info(
        ctx = ctx,
        toolchain_identifier = "k8-toolchain",
        host_system_name = "local",
        target_system_name = "local",
        target_cpu = "k8",
        target_libc = "unknown",
        compiler = "clang",
        abi_version = "unknown",
        abi_libc_version = "unknown",
    )

cc_toolchain_config = rule(
    implementation = _impl,
    attrs = {},
    provides = [CcToolchainConfigInfo],
)
```

Bazel version 4.1.0.

I see the global functions at [https://bazel.build/rules/lib/globals], but there is no indication I would have to load them, or how to even do that.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

Found out why after asking friends.

Bazel has a sort of declaration-definition file distinction. Functions like `rule` belong in definition files.

I got it working by moving the affected sections from declaration file (BUILD) to a definition file (.bzl), expose contents by macros etc, and finally have declaration file load it and use it.

`filegroup` similarly only works in declaration file, not definition.